# Is there a way to set a static reference (no bindings) to an object via Handlebars?

Tags: ember.js

jsFiddle speaks louder than words: http://jsfiddle.net/EAafK/1/

Every view has at least one dependency like this. And the controller never changes. So I was wondering, is there a way to connect the view to the controller instance via handlebars, like I'm trying to do in the "directController" case? Otherwise, we are going to have a ton of bindings that don't really do anything because the controllers don't change.

But maybe that's ok? Should we be worried about having a lot of unused bindings in an Ember application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve for both situations with the following:

```
App.View = Ember.View.extend({
  controller: null, // to be set at construction time
  modelBinding: 'controller.model',    
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("Hello, {{model}}!"),

  init: function() {
    var controller = (Ember.typeOf(this.get('controller')) == "string") ? Ember.getPath(this.get('controller')) : this.get('controller');

    this.set('controller', controller);

    this._super();
  }
});
```

I've also forked and updated [your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/wC3aW/).

Comment: Assuming Ember has no built-in way to do this, then I like your approach. I would probably work that into some sort of base view class to avoid redundant code. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6zTc5/1/

Comment: For anyone else interested in this, here's a more complicated example, which shows how flexible this pattern is and how you can use it with unit tests: http://jsfiddle.net/AZqAX/6/

Comment: No there is no built-in way to do this (yet). And no you should never hardcode controllers into views as you're doing in `App.ViewWithInlineControllerRef`. That violates core MVC principles in Ember. *Side Note*: I have a personal extension where I can do `{{view App.SomeView controllerGetObj="App.directController"}}` so this being built in is possible, but I'm not quite ready to submit a pull request to see if the core team would want to include something like that into Ember's core. For one I'm not sold on the 'GetObj' verb and the code is still messy though it works. Maybe one day...